# Running Drupal application on a webfarm (scalability ) , HOW?

Tags: php, drupal, scalability

We have created a website using Drupal , but the problem ( good problem ) is that we are getting WAAAAYY too many hits on the server to the point where the traffic is brining the server down to its knees.

now we want to run the application off of 3 servers behind a load balancer, one to just serve mysql and the other 2 to serve the web application , i have accomplished this using Symofony before for a different project and it was relatively easy.

However i don't seem to be able to get far with Drupal, the major problem at this point is to be able to save all session variables into mysql, so indepdent of which server the load balancer sends the request to , the application has a single point of reference in regards to sessions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, i am looking for a good tutorial or documentation since i have inherited this project off of a guy who no longer works here :/

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:** in my answer answer I'm assuming you are using Apache. My answer will be correct even if you are using some other server like nginx etc.

You write:

> However i don't seem to be able to get
>   far with Drupal, the major problem at
>   this point is to be able to save all
>   session variables into mysql, so
>   indepdent of which server the load
>   balancer sends the request to , the
>   application has a single point of
>   reference in regards to sessions.reference in regards to sessions.

Sessions are something that are handled at the core PHP level *and* at the Drupal+MySQL level. Essentially when a browser accesses your server, PHP core session handling logic assigns a unique PHPSESSID cookie. This cookie is sent back by that browser on every subsequent request.

[On a side note, using PHPSESSID, PHP core session logic might associate some other data like comment preferences, drupal messages that need to be shown on next page view etc. All this is done using the $_SESSION PHP variable. PHP does this quite seamlessly. Note that MySQL *still* does not enter in the picture until this point. MySQL only enters the picture when additional data needs to be associated with a PHPSESSID such as User ID etc. by Drupal]

Long story short, PHP does some session handling by assigning the PHPSESSID cookie. Now lets say the load balancer sends the request to Apache Webserver 1 and mod_php (PHP apache module) assigns a unique PHPSESSID, say, "563" (its a longer string in real life). Now next time this client accesses your website, the cookie PHPSESSID is sent across with value 563. Now two different cases might occur:

1. The load balancer (coincidently) sends the request to Apache 1 which originally assigned the PHPSESSID cookie. It recognizes 567 and things work fine
2. The load balancer sends the request to Apache 2. PHPSESSID is 567 which Apache 2 mod_php never assigned. So it gets confused and assigns a fresh PHPSESSID. This is where your problems occur.

**How to solve your problem**: The problem you're facing is a common issue. You simply need to tell the load balancer that once a client is sent to a particular web server, the *same* webs server should continue dealing with that request. This is usually done by telling the load balancer *itself* to send a cookie saying which server deal with the initial request. In the future, the client presents this cookie to the load balancer and the load balancer directs the request to the original server that deal with the request. This as I explained above is important because only *that* server knows about the PHPSESSID it assigned.

All decent load balancers have the ability to assign cookies. Look up the configuration details for your load balancer.reference in regards to sessions.

**More mind bending stuff** After you've solved your sessions issue by configuring your load balancer to assign cookies you will need to consider one more important issue. The `files` folder of both your server MUST be shared some how. This makes sense. If an image is uploaded by a user on one server, other people accessing the site through the other server should have access to the same image. This is accomplished by an `NFS (Networked File System)` mount or a SAN.

Only *then* you will have a fully functioning multi server installation of Drupal. As other people have pointed out, you might want to refer to some reference articles on the net. Further optimizations are recommended such as storing the sessions table in memcache and not in MySQL but again this has nothing to do with what I wrote above. Load balancer issuing cookies is really required.

Why go through so much grief I ask? I've done multi server stuff in the past and its not really worth it unless your site is getting some serious traffic. Is your traffic huge enough? Putting up a caching layer like Varnish in front of Drupal or even better, using the `boost` module should solve your problems if most of your users are anonymous.

Check out this video http://sf2010.drupal.org/conference/sessions/24-million-page-views-day-60-m-month-one-server . The guy is serving out a crazy number of page views using only 1 server. Everything is so much simpler with one server. Try it out! Only the hugest of websites may require multiple servers.

Comment: Sorry to bump and old issue, but I can't understand why need a load balancer issuing cookies. Cookies are stored in browser, so each machine can read the same cookie data, and access the same session data (stored unified). If cookie has the session_id, why the need to mantain the user to specific machine? Thanks! :)

Comment: Each webhead or webserver will have its own PHP interpreter. Each PHP interpreter will not know about the PHP sessions of other webservers. The load balancer needs to issue cookies which associate a particular browser with a particular webserver. So when the browser assesses the site again, the load balancer will forward the connection to the webserver that knows that particular Drupal session.

Answer (score 1):

You may get some ideas from Drupal.org's [Server tuning considerations](http://drupal.org/node/2601) and [Simple Decision Tree for Drupal Enterprise Scalability](http://drupal.org/node/51567).

Answer (score 1):

**Change core to Pressflow**

http://pressflow.org/

**Agregate js and css**

http://drupal.org/project/css_gzip

http://drupal.org/project/javascript_aggregator

**Use caching**

*nginx + Authcache + memcache + Easy authcache*

http://drupal.org/node/110224

http://drupal.org/project/authcache

http://drupal.org/project/memcache

http://drupal.org/node/916742

Or

*nginx + Varnish + ESI + memcache*

http://drupal.org/node/110224

http://drupal.org/project/varnish

http://drupal.org/project/esi

Also check 
http://getpantheon.com/

Answer (score 0):

Nice problem to have. Not one easy answer.

Have you looked at [memecached](http://drupal.org/project/memcache) for the caching that can help.

As can using [varnish](http://iskra.net/blog/ekes/2009/04/08/varnishing-over-drupal) in front of Drupal for certain caching.

Of course I assume that you already have tweaked your performance settings. For normal or  even aggressive caching if you can.

For sessions, you can get your load balancer set to sticky sessions so that users will keep gonig to the same server. You can even use varnish as your load balancer for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand why the other answers did not simply recommend to store the PHP session into MySQL. This way any server from the farm can answer any request seamlessly. The limitation with this scenario is that the application needs to either be stateless, or to maintain state though either PHP session data or some alternative that allows for such states to be recuperated by a another server (for example stored in MySQL by app instead of relying on session, or directly within the page data that will be re-posted to allow for continuation - all those scenarios imply an overhead that should be avoided when possible but is made necessary by this load balancing scenario).

Any Drupal modules that stores any data locally (i.e. files) will not work without some tinkering but in most other cases it should work fine. Saved files should be replicated across servers, this could be achieved by having all the web application files stored on networked file system, this should work well as long there is no bottleneck at the IO level. Alternatives are to replicate dynamic files via scripts, this can easily become a complicated and error prone process. Solutions to keep file systems in sync do exist but their reliability needs to be carefully assessed as unpredictable errors (network or file system related) will probably lead to either stopping the sync process or having discrepancies which will have to be manually addressed.

PHP sessions in MySQL are achieved by using this custom session handler such as : [PHP-MySQL-Sessions](https://github.com/dominicklee/PHP-MySQL-Sessions)